# CSS transition on height auto only working when adding class, not when removing class

Tags: html, css, sass

The goal is to use CSS transition on the height of a div changing from `0` to `auto` height so it slides open and closed as a visual.

Because CSS `height: auto` can't have transition, I used `max-height` as the transition. When I add the class "expanded" the height is then auto...

But when toggling the height on and off, it transitions only when adding the class. Removing the class (changing the height back to 0 and max-height back to 0) the transition doesn't exist and it is instant

```
.information{
  height: 0;
  max-height: 0;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: -1;
  background: #434C69;
  transition: max-height 700ms ease-in-out;


  &.expanded{
    height: auto;
    max-height: 500px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid $secondary-blue;
  }
 }
```

Comment: How are you managing the toggle? This is expected behaviour though I believe.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's the `height`, you are adding `transition` on `max-height` but your `height` changes to `0` instantly when you remove expanded class.

You can set `height: auto;` on the `.information` class with transition only on `max-height`.

```
.information{
  height: auto;
  max-height: 0;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: -1;
  background: #434C69;
  transition: max-height 700ms ease-in-out;


  &.expanded{
    max-height: 500px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid $secondary-blue;
  }
 }
```

Comment: faster than me :D, you can also remove height:0 in the first and let the auto on the second

Comment: even eaiser: no need to specify height at all for both classes

Comment: here is a fiddle for that https://jsfiddle.net/u2qwLjeo/. max-height not necessary here and transitions goes to height

Comment: @MattOpen, you're assuming that he wants a predefined height. I think he wants to use height: auto; because then he can let the content decide how high the container will be.

Answer (score 0):

you should create a class which it reverses the affect of information class and assign it instead of removing information class.
I hope it will be useful.